# Is there any reason to post bug questions on meta.J.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, meta

Simple enough. While in the past, SE mods have responded to bug reports on this meta, recently they have not.

Is there any reason we should post bug questions here rather than on meta.SO?

If not, should those already posted here be migrated and the [bug](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag removed?

Comment: They don't always answer [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115942/can-one-person-have-two-votes-to-delete) either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your community is here.  It is not expected that you live on Meta Stack Overflow.  Bug reports are absolutely valid here.  We do actively monitor the child metas.  Posting on MSO will obviously result in a post being seen by more people, but it'll still get seen here.

Things are a bit crazy with holiday schedules and end-of-year vacations, my apologies if something has been missed.  If something is still unresolved, add a comment pointing me to a post.

> Posting on a child meta ***is absolutely fine***!
>
> The Stack Exchange team monitors all of the child metas.  The child
>   metas do have a smaller reach than MSO, so posting on the child meta
>   to get an initial gauge of support, and then if necessary, bringing
>   that to MSO for a wider audience is fine.  *But there is no reason to
>   turn a post away from a child meta.*  Not everyone is involved with
>   the entire network.  They don't know that there is anything beyond
>   their meta, and they shouldn't be received poorly because of it.
>
> Think of this community as a state.  This community's meta is the state
>   capital.  Meta Stack Overflow is the nation's capital.  The state
>   functions, it just gets a little help from the nation's capital.
>
> In keeping with network policy, an answer on child meta that contains
>   links *should not just be a list of links*.  The post should also
>   summarize/explain what the links are.  Information can be found in
>   many places, and we should not be forcing users to go on a wild goose
>   chase to find information.
>
> [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232/140548)

Comment: Thanks Rebecca. Just FTR, my concern was not the delay on responses, it just provided the impetus for this general question. I appreciate that this is a busy time for everyone. Happy Holidays!