# How should we get responses from SE?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

(Warning: the tone of the following is meant to be taken in good humor.)

Ok, so let's say, theoretically of course, that someone has a question that ideally should (or must) be answered (or at least addressed) by SE staff. Let's assume further that SE staff had previously [advised](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/is-there-any-reason-to-post-bug-questions-on-meta-j-se) that such questions could and should be posted here rather than Meta.SO. Imagine further, that users posted [one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697) of these questions. Or [two](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/feature-request-indication-of-former-mod-status-on-answers-and-comments). Or [three](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-happens-to-a-flag-when-the-community-deletes-the-post-before-its-actioned). Or [four](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/632/feature-request-poll-question-for-meta-sites). Or [five](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/auto-generated-chat-event-announcement-says-right-now-early). (Is [six](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/611/allow-editing-of-site-specific-tag-wikis-in-meta) pushing it?)

Picture if you will, that none of these were answered or even addressed by SE staff for some time. These questions came from regular users, as well as our local mods. What action should be taken?

- <strike>Picket</strike> Occupy SE's offices in New York.
- None. (We can't expect them to actually respond to all of our kvetches.)
- Cry. Pout. Repeat.
- Attempt to reach an SE employee by:

  - Email.
  - Asking a site mod to super-ping them.
  - Commenting on a random post of theirs so that they get an inbox notification.
  - Smoke Signals.
  - Telepathy.
  - The classifieds.
  - Other. (Please specify.)
- Try to get an answer on Meta.SO by:

  - Posting a duplicate there.
  - Asking a mod to migrate it.
  - Wishing very, *very*, hard.
- Get a life.

Anybody have any ideas? Any SE mods? ;)

(Sorry about the general silliness of this question, but there's a double dose of Friday in Iceland today =D.)

Comment: As an aside, am I right in thinking that there should be am apostrophe in "comment of theirs"? If so, where?

Comment: It actually *is* Friday in UTC right now. (BTW, [no apostrophe](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26328) in "theirs".)

Comment: @jake I know, that's why I said a double dose. Thanks for the punctuation tip. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have brought this issue up to SE staff, and the response was that if you think a post here on meta hasn't gotten the attention it deserves from SE staff, tell us mods. If we agree, we'll bother them about it.

Comment: I'm just curious, the last two questions are your own, and though they are three weeks old, they have no responses. What's going on?

Comment: @HodOfHod I didn't bother SE staff about them before now.

Comment: Then perhaps the mods (either site or network) should regularly check the "feature-request" and "bug" tags, dealing with those they can and (for site-mods) passing on up those that have been missed by SE staff?

Comment: @HodOfHod Network mods (SE staff) do check in from time to time, but I get the sense that there are more sites now than they have time to keep up with all of the requests and bugs from. I won't commit to a particular schedule, but I'll try (B"N) to the the sort of sweep you suggest from time to time. Also, do feel free to bug me/us in chat or via comment-ping (if we happen to have asked, answered, or commented on the post you're interested in, which is usually the case).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I realize that you and they both are busy people, so thanks for all that you do. I think that perhaps for network-wide "bugs" and "feature-requests", they should be asked on meta.so, to make it easier to keep track of them. But that's just me, and Rebecca has said otherwise.

Comment: Part of a moderator's role is to be a liaison between the site community and SE employees.  Moderators have direct access to a number of SE employees and can point us at things as escalation requires.